# Python create all possible combinations from a integer

Tags: python

I have integer for example "123", using this i want to create all possible combinations listed below.
123
12,3
1,23 and so on irrespective of the digits i have entered.
Is there any way possible using python for the same? I am not able to get any idea.

Comment: Have you looked at the itertools module and the combinations/permutations functions?

Comment: Yes itertools gives me an output like "['123', '132', '213', '231', '312', '321']". But i need a output of 123 to be like (1,2,3) , (12,3), (1,23) and so on

Comment: Your question is currently too vague. Is order significant? Should the output contain (1,32)? Should it contain (1,2,3) and (3,1,2)?

Comment: Are you asking for all partitions of the set of numbers `1,2,3`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893292/generate-all-partitions-of-a-set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
num = 123
s = str(num)
[[x for x in i if x is not '' and ' '] for i in [list(s.partition(item)) for item in list(s+' ')]]
```

Output:

```
[['1', '23'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['12', '3'], ['123']]
```

You could also use tuples:

```
s = str(num)
[tuple([x for x in i if x is not '' and ' ']) for i in [list(s.partition(item)) for item in list(s+' ')]]
```

Output:

```
[('1', '23'), ('1', '2', '3'), ('12', '3'), ('123',)]
```

Comment: This is probably what the OP wants, but guessing can be dangerous if you guess wrong. ;) BTW, it's generally not a good idea to use `is` to test strings, since `is` tests identity, not value. It works ok here because CPython optimizes the empty string, and it will often work with short strings that get re-used by the interpreter, but it won't always work. See [Why does comparing strings in Python using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1504717/4014959) for further details.

Comment: BTW, `if x is not '' and ' '` is interpreted as `if (x is not '') and ' '`, and therefore it's logically equivalent to `if x`. The empty string has a boolean value of `False`, and any other string has a boolean value of `True`. So if `x` is the empty string, `x is not ''` evaluates to `False`, so the `if` test fails. Otherwise, `x is not ''` evaluates to `True`, the second operator of `and` (`' '`) becomes the value of the expression, so the `if` test passes.

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice the `if (x is not '') and ' '` part. Although surprisingly, my code did remove the trailing and leading `''` and `' '` just the way I needed.

Comment: But what if there's '123' as the input and apart from the outputs obtained above, I also need to get ['2','13'] as part of the output? any suggestions. i'm basically stuck trying to figure something out here.

Comment: @PM2Ring request your help for the same

Comment: @gireesh4manu If none of the existing questions do what you want you should ask a new question. Clearly state the full output you want for the '123' input, and include your own code attempt (otherwise your question may be closed).

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
import itertools

stuff = list('123')
for L in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
  for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
    print(subset)
```

Output:

```
()
(1,)
(2,)
(3,)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: I want the output of "123" to be like (1,2,3) , (12,3), (1,23) and so on

Comment: @srivathsakenkere edit the question