# Find all disjoint sets of any size that cover a given set

Tags: python, combinatorics

I have a set of elements `A = {a, b, c, d, e, f}`

I want to get all sets of disjoint sets of any size that cover A. So `{{{a,b}, {c,d,e,f}}, {{a,b}{c,d,e}{f}}, {{a,b,c}{d,e,f}}...}`, etc.

Is there an easy (not too slow) way of doing this?  Ideally in python, but the general algorithm would also be appreciated.

I tried getting the power-set of the power-set to then filter out the sets with disjoint sets, but that blows up too quickly and kills my computer.

The purpose is to find all possible subtrees in a tree make make up that tree again.

Comment: "but that blows-up too quickly and kills my computer." - The size of the set you are attempting to construct is exponential, for the power set is a subset of your set. So, it is not clear what you mean by "easy (not too slow) way of doing this"

Comment: Does {{a,c,e},{b,d,f}} count?

Comment: You're looking to generate all partitions of the set. Here's a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530128/how-to-find-all-partitions-of-a-set) that addresses this problem:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all partitions of a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530128/how-to-find-all-partitions-of-a-set)