# Can anyone show me an algorithm to create a function that returns all possible partitions of an array into n subsets while maintaining order of array?

Tags: arrays, array-algorithms

The function would basically just generate all of the ways to partition an array into n buckets while keeping the order of the original array. It would generate an array of arrays of arrays

**Function signature:**

```
func(arr, n)
arr = an array of numbers
n = int <= length(arr)
```

Example function calls:

```
func([1, 2, 3], 1) would return [ [[1, 2, 3]] ]
func([1, 2, 3], 2) would return [ [[1],[2, 3]], [[1, 2],[3]]]
func([1, 2, 3], 3) would return [ [[1], [2], [3]] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out.

I did it by
1. implementing algorithm in this post - [How to find all partitions of a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530128/how-to-find-all-partitions-of-a-set/30903689#30903689)
2. filter out partitions with elements that do not maintain the order of the original array
3. filter out partitions that are not of size n